# Is Mew required to complete the Pokedex?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

This question is based on three assumptions (which I assume to be true - please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. You can only obtain Mew by purchasing a Pokeball Plus, which contains exactly one Mew
2. You can't breed Pokemon in the Let's Go games
3. You can't transfer any Pokemon that didn't already come from another Let's Go game to a Let's Go game through Pokemon Home

Considering all of that, it seems to me that the number of Mews in Let's Go world-wide is finite. So if you only pick up the game now and are missing the Pokeball Plus, are you unable to complete the Pokedex unless you happen to meet someone by chance who is willing to trade you their Mew?

**TL;DR: Is Mew required to complete the Pokedex in Let's Go Pikachu/Eevee?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

To officially complete the Pokédex, you need to catch the **first 150 Pokémon** in the game, from Bulbasaur to Mewtwo.
Having Mew, Meltan, and Melmetal registered to the device will certainly give you bragging rights, but they don’t count toward the final tally.

Mythicals are always excluded from Pokedex completion.

Comment: (shrug) Not sure if having Meltan and Melmetal registered in Let's Go is considered worthy enough for bragging rights. I currently have roughly 100 Meltans just hanging out in the Pokemon GO Park

Comment: @Wondercricket objection accepted